# www to non-www redirect error in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=CWD:%2]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ %{ENV:CWD}$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) %{ENV:CWD}$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:CWD}./index.php?rewrite=$1
```

It works great, but if I put it in a subdirectory, the redirection to non-www doesn't work. I tried to use the `%{ENV:CWD}` environment variable which I made at the top, but it didn't work.

How can I make it work when htaccess is in a subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put your .htaccess file in a subdirectory, then you need to change this:

**from**

```
RewriteBase /
```

**to**

```
RewriteBase /subdirectory
```

Also try this: (without the `RewriteCond`)

```
  RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I can't change the RewriteBase because I don't know the where the document root will be. That's why I created the `%{ENV:CWD}` variable but i don't know where to put it.